# SocketIO in React Native App sometimes leads to 500/502 with iOS Clients

Tags: react-native, nginx, socket.io

I have a Node.js express app running behind nginx, it includes a route/namespace for socketio as well. My client is a react native app, which uses socket.io-client for some stuff to communicate to the backend.

Everything works as expected, however sometimes, nginx logs errors for those routes. This represents **a small percentage of all socketIO related calls**, from the logs it seems like all of the devices are iOS devices. There are 3 types of errors being logged:

GET:

> SomeIP - - [09/Jun/2020:10:43:08 +0200] "GET /v1/socket/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NAOFrmt HTTP/2.0" 502 150 "-" "Backend/236 CFNetwork/978.0.7 Darwin/18.7.0"

POST:

> SomeIP - - [09/Jun/2020:10:43:08 +0200] "POST /v1/socket/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=awdlkaw3&sid=aDLakwdlkWDLk HTTP/2.0" 502 150 "-" "Backend/236 CFNetwork/978.0.7 Darwin/18.7.0"

500:

> SomeIP - - [08/Jun/2020:21:27:52 +0200] "GET /v1/chatSocket/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=AWKDHJ&sid=LKWAJDLKJAWDLAKWJD HTTP/2.0" 500 0 "-" "Backend/236 CFNetwork/1125.2 Darwin/19.4.0"

I am struggling to understand why this is happening. Again, everything seems to work fine and the clients how caused above errors, **will get successful 2xx responses only seconds afterwards when polling.** It seems like only some of the polling fails. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I'm also using a node server with nginx and sometimes i'm also having the same problem actually but connection is working as i expected. I never checked into nginx logs actually but i'm sure if i do i'll find these kind of errors too. I think it's just a tiny gap time between changing to http to websockets?

Comment: @HalilÇakar Yes it almost seems like this is normal behaviour.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's normal but as far as i can see everything works fine even this happens for more then a second